# Implement In App purchases in Android using Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, in-app-purchase, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I want to implement in App purchase in Android Platform using Phonegap. I used one plugin available in Cordova.

Plugin: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/cc.fovea.cordova.purchase

But I can't open default play store dialogue of In App purchase.
I can't resolve it. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lots of research I got solution. May be it helpful for all
https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I upvoted your question. Thanks for finding an answer.